# Twig inception - how do you parse a Twig template that's in a variable?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'd like to pass a twig variable through twig, with the knowledge of the current data.  I suppose a simplistic version would be

```
{% set temp = '{{ myId }} is my identifier' %}

{{ temp|twig }}
```

Where the `twig` filter would look at the data *in the current context* and replace `{{ myId }}` with whatever the value of `myId` was that was passed to the original template?  Is that even possible?

**Please note** that it must be a filter that acts upon the current value of `temp`.  I don't know what that template will be in advance, it will be calculated effectively at runtime.  In short, **I need to parse a Twig template from inside a Twig template**.

Comment: Something like https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/template_from_string.html ?

Comment: Algy look at the link from @PatrickQ and maybe this also helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803353/render-content-from-string-database-and-generate-links-with-twig

Comment: @PatrickQ - you're right, it is a duplicate of that.  Thanks for your help, though, and also Caramba ... solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Try like so

```
{% set temp = myId ~ ' is my identifier' %}

{{ temp }}
```

in twig string concatenation works with `~`

If you need to pass HTML also in the variable you can do like so

```
{% set temp = '<h1>' ~ myId ~ ' is my identifier</h1>' %}

{{ temp | raw }}
```

or depending on what `myId` is. If it gets more comlicated you might want to create a [twig macro](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html) see especially on the [{% import _self as forms %}](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html#import) so you can create the macro in the same file where you need it if you need it only in that particular file.

Comment: You are right, but it **has** to be passed as a template string.  I'll add a little to the question to clear up the confusion :)

Comment: @AlgyTaylor what do you mean by "template string"?

Comment: hopefully the _please note_ section and rephased example helps a little.  ``temp`` **is** a twig template, so I need a filter/function/whatever that will parse a twig template _from inside a twig template_.

Comment: heya @caramba -- thanks for your help.    I can't do your updated answer either, unfortunately - the value of ``temp`` can't be changed, that comes out as a Twig template inside a string (as the example).