# Twig template section with variable

Tags: twig

Im writing little CMS, for this project Im using Laravel/Lumen FW and Twig engine for templates. 
I would like to had option to dynamically edit front page, and her sections. Sections of my front page, are stored in mySQL base as text where I putting my html code of section. Section is printed by Twig, by for statement.

Everything work's fine until, I put another variable into my section content in mySQL base.

I does it becouse I want to made child element for my section, which could be displayed only into her area.

Twig for loop:

```
    {% for section in sections %}
      {{ section.content }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Value of section.content in mySQL base:

```
Lorem ipsum {{ section.name }}
```

Result which I saw is plain text, without rendering by twig, so it looks like content in base.

```
Lorem ipsum {{ section.name }}
```

What could I do to print variable inside other variable in Twig engine?

Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly You can use the twig function attribute to access a "dynamic" attribute of a variable:

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render content from string/database and generate links with twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803353/render-content-from-string-database-and-generate-links-with-twig)

Comment: @Med Problem existing when I trying to print any variable into another variable.

Ex.:
{{ header }}

and content of header will be for ex.:
Example plain tekst before ad link {{ adlink }}

Variable cannot be embedded into another variable, its any way to fix it?